Force appointment reminders to the beginning of global-mode-string
Is there a way to have appt-mode-string added to the beginning of global-mode-string?  It is added to the end, and thus appointment reminders show up after all the other information, like this:

Setting global-mode-string by hand has no effect, I always end up with a value like
 ("" battery-mode-line-string display-time-string appt-mode-string) 

The reason seems to be that the function appt-activate deletes appt-mode-string and then does (append global-mode-string '(appt-mode-string))) when updating the reminder.
Reason: in recent versions, Emacs can display global-mode-string at the right edge of the tab-bar.  Because of the alignment to the right, transient information like appointment reminders should be added to the beginning of the string, not the end.

Can you reorder items in the global-mode-string list?

No. As I said, appt-activate re-appends appt-mode-string each time it updates.

You can use an advice to reorder elements afterwards:
(define-advice appt-activate (:after (&rest _args) reorder)
  "Reorder `appt-mode-string' in `global-mode-string'."
  (when (memq 'appt-mode-string global-mode-string)
    (setq global-mode-string
      (append '("" appt-mode-string)
          (delq 'appt-mode-string (cdr global-mode-string))))))


This seems to cause appointment reminders to disappear entirely...
